How to sort strings in alphabetical order?
I need to write program does the following:

stores three unsorted strings entered from the keyboard into three string variables a, b and c. After loading the variables, your program will sort the values in alphabetical order, that is, store into a the smallest string,in b the middle one and in c the largest.

I am working in C++.
I've gotten this far:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a, b, c, temp;

    cout << "enter a word" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "enter a different word" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "enter a third word" << endl;
    cin >> c;
    if (a < b && a < c) {
        if (b < c) {
            cout << endl;
            cout << a << endl;
            cout << b << endl;
            cout << c << endl;
        }
        else {
            temp = c;
            c = b;
            b = temp;
            cout << endl;
            cout << a << endl;
            cout << b << endl;
            cout << c << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (b > c) {
            temp = a;
            a = c;
            c = temp;
            cout << endl;
            cout << a << endl;
            cout << b << endl;
            cout << c << endl;
        }
        else {
            temp = a;
            a = c;
            c = temp;
            temp = b;
            b = a;
            a = temp;
            cout << endl;
            cout << a << endl;
            cout << b << endl;
            cout << c << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

As is, the program does return "abc, acb, cab and cba" as desired (abc), however, I cannot figure out how to address "bac and bca" entries to return as abc.  I need to understand if an additional statement is needed or if I need to add/alter my current if/else statements.

using namespace std; -- Why oh why? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3962537 | And why is (was before someone cleaned it up for you) that code all over the place?

Side note:noting in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

It's probably cheating, but I'd create an array of three strings, copy a, b, and c into it, sort it with std::sort, and copy the array elements out into a, b, and c. One big benefit of this approach over all those hard-coded comparisons is that when the next problem asks you to sort four strings instead of three the change is much simpler.

so, I need any three words entered into the program to be sorted back into the display in in alphabetical order.  The program is working, but I need to be able to run all 6 possible variations (abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba).  I hope I am explaining my question correctly.  I have been able to get the program to spit back out all but the variations which begin with what should be the middle word when properly organized.

In alphabetical order, I would argue that there is no concept of "small" or "large." In any case, you could implement an algorithm like bubble sort without an array. You don't need to print any combination of the variables a, b, and c. You need to print the words in lexicographical order. There is a big difference. I forgot how many lines this program is, but mine is 32 lines (I at least used std::swap). With an array and std::sort, it would be much shorter.

as I understand it, a string is larger in ascii if it comes later in the english alphabet

for my purposes, what I need is to be able to type in any word for 'a', any word for 'b' and any word for 'c' and then have each of those words organized into alphabetical order.  so, 'a' could be zebra, 'b' foam and 'c' yellow and have those words re-displayed: 'foam, yellow, zebra'...

@lealdrake If you follow the steps I showed in the answer, you will get foam, yellow, zebra.

std::vector<std::string> strings;  std::cin >> a; strings.push_back(a)... std::sort(strings.begin(), std::sort(strings.end(); and then for(const auto& string : strings) std::cout << string << "\n"; This will also work when you have more than three strings.

Characters do have an integer value assigned to them. Characters are not strings. Thinking of characters as numbers can be occasionally useful. You also have not cleared up whether lexicographical sorting suffices, or if it must be "true" alphabetical.  For instance std::string{"Zebra"} < std::string{"yellow"} is true.

Pepijn, why are you using 'std' so much?

sweenish, for sake of clarity, I need whatever words are inputted to display in the order previously exemplified, so 'foam, yellow, zebra', regardless of whether the order the words were entered in were zebra, foam and yellow; foam, zebra, yellow or yellow, zebra foam; or yellow, foam, zebra; or foam, yellow, zebra; zebra yellow, foam.  it should end up being displayed as 'foam, yellow, zebra'.

You are misunderstanding me. String comparisons sort lexicographically, and not alphabetically. For example, again, the words "foam," "yellow," and "Zebra" (note the capital 'Z') would create the ordering "Zebra," "foam," "yellow" because that is lexicographical order. You keep saying "alphabetical," and that usually means "regardless of capitalization," which usually means that you have to handle that in your code. However, if casing is always the same, then lexicographical ends up being alphabetical. These details are important to know and distringuish.

You have 3 variables and the contained strings and in this example the strings will be C, B and A.











variable
a
b
c


string
C
B
A



And you want to sort them lexicographically. For this you could use bubble-sort which will require three comparisons and potentially three swaps.

If b < a then swap a and b, and since that's true, you'll get:












variable
a
b
c


string
B
C
A




If c < b then swap b and c. This is also true in this case, so you end up with












variable
a
b
c


string
B
A
C



The third and last step is a repetition of the first step.

If b < a then swap a and b, and since that's true, you'll get:












variable
a
b
c


string
A
B
C



Note that std::swap is part of the standard library and std::string has a swap member function, so your code would eventually look something like this:
if(b < a) a.swap(b);
if(c < b) b.swap(c);
if(b < a) a.swap(b);

A small optimization could be to exclude the last check if the second check turns out false. If that's the case, we already know that b < a can not be true.
if(b < a) a.swap(b);
if(c < b) {
    b.swap(c);
    if(b < a) a.swap(b);
}


I like the concrete comparisons approach given the small size of inputs. My non-array bubble sort still used a loop, which allowed adding extra comparisons if necessary, but it's not necessary in this case.

@sweenish Thanks! Yeah, it looked like OP was on the way to implement a bubble-sort -like algorithm, but mixed it up a bit, so I hope reading about bubble-sort and seeing this case with only three elements will make it easy to understand how it works. I was about to go on using an array or std::vector with std::sort which would be the idiomatic solution, but I have a feeling OP has not read about containers and algorithms in C++ yet so I tried to stay as close to OP's code that I could.

Ted, thank you for this - I am not allowed to use anything but strings, if/else, etc.  I have not encountered those other things you mentioned...

@lealdrake You are welcome! Just in case you are not allowed to use std::swap either, you can easily create your own by making a function that takes two std::strings by reference and then exchange their content, just like you now do using the variable temp - or use the std::string::swap member function. I updated the answer to use the std::string::swap function instead just in case.

Ok, I am back at, I will research this a bit more with your guidance here!  Thank you for your time!

@lealdrake You're welcome and good luck! Remember, the algorithm for sorting that I used is bubble-sort, so if you understand how bubble-sort works in the general case where you can have many elements, you should hopefully see how it works when specialized for only three elements as it is in this case. full example
